# Enumerate through list of object and return index or object

Tags: python, enumerate

I have a list of objects. 
One of the attribute in the list is m_expiry that is stored as string. 
I am trying to find the shortest date difference (between now and that attribute values) and get either the index of the list or the object itself.

Currently **expiryValue** is returning the date difference and not the index/object.(I would like it to return idx = 0 or object[0]

```
expiryValue = min((datetime.strptime(item.m_expiry,'%Y%m%d') -datetime.now()) for item in object)
```

15 days, 10:12:00.077586

```
    idx    id     x   y    z    a     m_expiry

    [0] 215465490 ES ESH7 FUT GLOBEX  20170317
    [1] 225652200 ES ESM7 FUT GLOBEX  20170616
    [2] 236950077 ES ESU7 FUT GLOBEX  20170915
    [3] 247950613 ES ESZ7 FUT GLOBEX  20171215
    [4] 258973438 ES ESH8 FUT GLOBEX  20180316
```

Comment: Can you improve your question? Elaborate it better ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  The trick here is to minimise the items, *keying off their timedelta*, as opposed to minimising the timedeltas themselves.

Take a minimum over the items, and use the `key` keyword argument of `min`.

```
min(items, key=...)
```

The key function, which you will define, should accept an item and return the timedelta for that item.  You should also take care to make the absolute value of the timedelta, which you aren't doing in your example code.

This will return the item itself, which has already the index on it which you can access at `item.idx`.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Include: from operator import attregetter